# Calling stored procedures from two different schemas MySQL in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I tried this code with a CRON schedule, but it doesn't fire. How can I put everything in one PHP file and call different stored procedures located in different schemas? I am connecting to the first schema in the beginning of this PHP file:

```
try {
    // Return errors
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// Begin transaction
$db->beginTransaction();
$stm1 = $db->prepare("CALL schema1.sp1()");
$stm1 ->execute();

$stm2 = $db->prepare("CALL schema1.sp2()");
$stm2 ->execute();

$stm3 = $db->prepare("CALL schema2.sp1()");
$stm3 ->execute();

$stm4 = $db->prepare("CALL schema2.sp2()");
$stm4 ->execute();
```

Comment: define "doesn't fire". normally it should work if a user has acces to both schemas. Does it work for just one schema? No? Why do you mention two schemas then?

Comment: To be honest that looks correct  - I have just tried calling a stored procedure from another db ( admittedly in the gui and not using php ) like this
"CALL `contest`.`spUpdateContest`(100)" and it worked fine

Comment: @ YCS for "doesn't fire" -  From what I can tell it doesn't get activated in the cron schedule when I use the above. I will mess with it some more and see it is throwing an error somewhere I can post.

Comment: @ RamRaider I thought this was the correct way as well since I use this technique for other stuff with mysql, but not sure if stored procedures are different.